# Laravel 6.x Include Model for Blade to use it in any view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a model called `Config`. The model is located in `App\Models\Config\Config.php` and the model should be used get config values from the database.

I want that I can use in the blade view the following:

```
{{Config::get("name","=","ConfigValueName")->first()}}
```

(get is replace in real with a custom method which returns exactly that)

When I do it that way, I get the exception:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Config\Repository::where()
```

I want to avoid to add to every Config get function call the path to the model.

What is the best way to solve this? My idea is that I change the Imports in the rendering class.

Comment: To use it in any view ? Then better to use a Helper method which will be available globaly. Put your query in a helper method and you are done.

Comment: Thats a brilliant idea @AkhtarMunir I didn't thougt of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to load your variable in all views you could try using `View::share()` [view share doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

example:

```
  View::share('key', 'value');
```

if you want a more advanced way to share variable only to specific view you can use `view composers` [view composers doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers)

simple example:

```
View::composer('view-name', function ($view) {
             $view->with('key', 'value');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
@php 
     $configVal = \App\Models\Config::where(['name'=>'ConfigValueName'])->first(); 

@endphp

{{$configVal}}
```